# What should helpstring of the interface contain?

Tags: c++, interface, idl

I've observed that different developers have different choice of texts to be specified in the help string. Some of the examples,

```
[
    helpstring ("My Interface"),
]
interface MyInterface : IUnknown
{
}
```

I don't know if this helpstring is useful at all (!?).

```
[
    helpstring ("Interface used with Module A to do some stuff."),
]
interface MyInterface : IUnknown
{
}
```

Good?

```
[
    helpstring ("Used to implement certain functionality."),
]
interface MyInterface : IUnknown
{
}
```

Many others.

Is there any guideline you follow when specifying `helpstring` of the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no guidelines that I am aware of.  I've seen many that are of the form "My Interface", which is useless.

If you know your target audience (in house developers, experienced third party developers, IT staff, etc), think of what skills they will likely have (and are perhaps required to use your interface) and what will help them.